# doubts about what do embeddings represent

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, embedding

```
import torch
from torch import nn
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
self.token_emb = nn.Embedding(num_tokens, dim)
x = token_emb(x)
```

I want to create embeddings with dimension "dim" for each rows through this code, this is correct or not? And why? I cannot understand if doing x.t() for example change something.

Comment: Your input is `B x S`. Your output will be `B x S x dim`. What output do you want?